# ASP.NET Core view only partially post back the ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a ViewModel that includes 4 different classes with a lot of properties.
Now, if I make a submit in my view, only the properties that are bound to an input field are posted back, which is bad, since I have a table based on one of those classes (which are gone after the submit).

I know I could handle it like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.class.property)
```

But with the amount of properties, this seems like a very inconvenient approach.
I could also just get my model via query again, but this also seems like an approach that's not right.

Is there a better approach than those I mentioned above?

**Edit:**
And I tried it this way too:

```
  @foreach (var property in Model.Mandant.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(p => property)
        }
```

But for some reasons this doesn't work, sadly.

**Edit2 for clarification:**
I have an viewModel like this:

```
  public class ValidationViewModel
        {
            public M_IV_INVOICE Invoice { get; set; }
            public List<M_IP_INVOICE_POS> Positions { get;}
            public S_KR_KREDITOR_ Kreditor { get; set; }
            public S_MD_MANDANTEN Mandant { get; set; }
    
            public ValidationViewModel() { }
            public ValidationViewModel(int invoiceId)
            {
                Invoice = CRUD.GetFirstOrDefault(new M_IV_INVOICE(), string.Format(@"WHERE M_IV_ID IN ({0})", invoiceId));
                Positions = Invoice != null ? CRUD.GetList(new M_IP_INVOICE_POS(), string.Format(@"WHERE M_IP_INVOICEID IN ({0})", Invoice.M_IV_ID)) : null;
                Kreditor = Invoice?.M_IV_KREDITOR != null ? CRUD.GetFirstOrDefault(new S_KR_KREDITOR_(), string.Format(@"WHERE S_KR_KREDITOR IN ({0})", Invoice.M_IV_KREDITOR), "S_KR_KREDITOR") : null;
                Mandant = Invoice?.M_IV_MANDANT != null ? CRUD.GetFirstOrDefault(new S_MD_MANDANTEN(), string.Format(@"WHERE S_MD_FIR IN ({0})", Invoice.M_IV_MANDANT)) : null;
        }

    }
```

I have a view which looks like this:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Home"))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary();
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-2">
                    @*@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Mandant.S_MD_FIR)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Mandant.S_MD_FIR, string.Format("{0} - {1}", Model.Mandant?.S_MD_FIR, Model.Mandant.S_MD_BEZEICHNUNG), new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "0" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Mandant.S_MD_FIR)*@
                    @Html.Label("Mandant")
                    <input readonly value="@string.Format("{0} - {1}", Model.Mandant?.S_MD_FIR, Model.Mandant?.S_MD_BEZEICHNUNG)" class="form-control" placeholder="" id="Mandant" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-2">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Invoice.M_IV_KREDITOR)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Invoice.M_IV_KREDITOR, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "0" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Invoice.M_IV_KREDITOR)
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-2">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Invoice.M_IV_INVOICEDATE)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Invoice.M_IV_INVOICEDATE, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "0" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Invoice.M_IV_INVOICEDATE)
                </div>
            </div>
.....
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
}
```

Now, if I press the button and call my update method:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Update(ValidationViewModel validationViewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                validationViewModel.Invoice.Update();
                // TODO additional logic
            }
            return View("Index", validationViewModel);
        }
```

Everything that's not bound to an input field or listed with:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Invoice.M_IV_ID)
```

is nulled.
And now I'm locking for a more convenient way to circumvent this, if even possible.

Comment: I don't think your question is clear enough for us to be able to help you. From what I've understood, you are trying to put ViewModel's child objects in the form model, right? The second approach does not work because the `property` is of type `PropertyInfo`, it's not something you'd like to put into a form model.

Comment: Hi, no, that's not the problem.
The problem is that if I make a submit, parts of my viewModel get lost (those, wich are not bind to an input field).
I'll try to clarify it in my questien via an edit

Comment: @DorinBaba I've updated my question, is that more clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET does not provide the behavior that you're looking for, as far as I know, there is no `@Html.HiddenForModel(model => model.child)`. I guess it's because if you have that level of data complexity on your view, you might want to simplify it and to present only what's necessary for the view. But you can try to "hack" it with `@Html.EditorForModel()`, wrapped within an invisible container on your view, something like the snippet below:

```
<div style="display: none">
  @Html.EditorForModel()
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.child1)
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.child2)
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.child3)
</div>
```

Comment: Ha, that's nice. that works.
And jeah, I only display the things I need, but since the positions are displayed in a table, and are not bound to an inputfield or something like this, they get deleted on submit. 
But what ever, I'm satisfied with your "hack", thank you ;)

Comment: Ah sorry, that I have to come back to you again, but it's not working for the position list.
Do you have a nice work around for that too?
(the positions are still null after the submit ;( )

Comment: I see that your Position list does not have a setter, only a getter, that might be the cause. Add `{ get; set; }` to Positions and try again

Comment: I tried it and that one didn't work ;(
(btw. I didn't used a set; there, because a list has a add / addRange function anyway)

Comment: If I put the position in a single entity instead of a list, it works like with the other. That's really strange, even if I bind every single position proerty to an input field, it doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, couldn't edit anymore, so:
Edit:
Okay, iit makes sense, really. The problem is, that the binding is not working this way.
I think I just refresh the viewModel after an Update, that would be the easiest way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

To further elaborate on my problem with the List object:
If I do it the way Dorin Raba showed in the answer:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.child1)
```

it won't work because, all the textfields are named without an index, so it's not possible to match the values back.

But I can simply do it this way:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.M_IP_INVOICE_POS.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.M_IP_INVOICE_POS[i])
    }
```

and now every editor field has the correct name and I get the positions back to the controller.
So no need to query my Positions every time I want to Update something.